# How to setup document archival for documents in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-server, retention

I am working with SharePoint on prem 2010. I have to propose a non-coding solution for one a retention/document archival job. Basically once a document is uploaded, after three years (we can calculate 3 years based on the created date assigned by SharePoint) we would like to copy/move it over to a different library under a different site collection's site.Once the move is performed then the document should be deleted from the Source library.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if a non-coding solution exists but you can do it with a small piece of PowerShell script and windows task scheduler. I did similar things many times.

Comment: Can you share some more info by an example or so, would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use PowerShell, you can use these scripts to copy files from one library to another. It will copy files only, if you have a folder structure, you should look at [this link](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/03/copy-files-between-document-libraries-using-powershell-in-sharepoint.html)

You can schedule a job using windows task scheduler to work every day. Also, add date control to this code, and it will work for you

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
cls

$sWeb=Get-SPWeb "http://sourceweb/"
$sList=$sWeb.Lists | ?{$_.Title -eq "SourceLib"}

$dWeb=Get-SPWeb "http://destinationweb"
$dList=$dWeb.Lists | ?{$_.Title -eq "DestinationLib"}

$RootFolder=$sList.RootFolder
$RootItems=$RootFolder.Files

foreach($RootItem in $RootItems)
{
        $sBytes = $RootItem.OpenBinary() 
        $dFile = $dList.RootFolder.Files.Add($RootItem.Name, $sBytes, $true)        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Record center site template to archive document. For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[Step by step configuring document archival in SharePoint 2010.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17927.step-by-step-configuring-document-archival-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

And you also could use workflow to archive document. For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

Archive SharePoint Library Documents.

https://www.kalmstrom.com/Tips/SharePointArchiveDocs.htm